# NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryPath returning empty

Tags: ios

I have an images group inside my xCode project. I am trying to get all the files from inside that folder into my app.

```
 NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Images/" error:nil];
```

The above code always returns an empty array. I added the group in xCode 4.2 by right click and then "New Group".

Comment: That I know but xCode does not allow u to add folders. How do I add folders and not logical groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you are using is probably not the correct one. `/Images/` will refer to images in the root of your sandbox. If the images in your folder are added as a resource in your project, they will be stored in the Resources directory in your app, probably not even in the `Images` directory.

You also want to read the error to see what's wrong. That's what it is for:

```
NSErorr *error = nil;
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Images/" error:&error];
if (!dirContents) {
    // inspect error
}
```

Use `-[NSBundle resourcePath]` to get a path to your applications resources directory.

Understand that your project structure is not equal to the location your resources will end up in your application. Resources are all copied to the Resources directory using your targets
`Copy Bundle Resources` buid phase.

If you really want to add certain files in a different directory in your resources directory add a new `Copy Files` phase, with a destination of `Resources` and a `Subpath` named with your folder, like `Images`

Then you can loop over those images using your file manager and the path you get using:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];
```

Comment: Yes the images folder is inside the Resources directory. How can I tell if it is a directory or a group since everything is colored as yellow. In previous xCode versions groups were colored as blue folders.

Comment: Understand that the layout in your project navigator is not the way your images will end up in your application. Your Copy Bundle Resources phase in your target will copy all image files to the Resources directory in your application, disregarding groups or directories in your project navigator. See my updated answer.